# Compare two rows in a DB2 table and compare corresponding data in second table

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

I have a list of transactions which can be uniquely identified by a transaction ID `t_id`. These transactions are classified by `type` 'D' (Debit) or 'C' (Credit). Some transactions  come along with additional information (`addinfo` = 'Y') about business partners and their charge

Credit transaction can only exist paired with a corresponding Debit transaction (as shown in my example). There are no such restrictions for Debit transactions.

```
TRANSACT
- t_id -|- type -|- price -|- addinfo
--------------------------------------
100001  |   D    |   2000  |        Y
100002  |   C    |  -2000  |        Y
100003  |   D    |   1000  |        Y
100004  |   C    |  -1000  |        Y
100005  |   D    |   3000  |        N   
100006  |   D    |   2000  |        Y
100007  |   C    |   1000  |        Y
```

```
PTRANSACT
- t_id -|- partner -|- charge
--------|-----------|--------
100001  |      AAA  |     200
100001  |      BBB  |     400
100002  |      AAA  |    -200
100002  |      BBB  |    -400
100003  |      AAA  |     100
100003  |      BBB  |     200
100004  |      AAA  |    -100
100006  |      CCC  |     600
100007  |      CCC  |    -300
```

I need to find a way to output only Debit transactions that are not (!) followed by a Credit transaction so that both transactions cancel each other out. They only cancel each other out, if both transactions are having the exact same partners and the sum of both charges for each partner is zero.

In my example, the transactions `100001` and `100002` have to be ignored. Therefore, the output schould look like:

```
- t_id -|- type -|- price -|- addinfo
--------------------------------------
100003  |   D    |   1000  |        Y
100005  |   D    |   3000  |        N   
100006  |   D    |   2000  |        Y
```

I'm fairly new to DB2 and SQL. I tried combining multiple `EXISTS()` and `JOIN` statements but I always end up also loosing transaction  `100003`.

I will update my post with my previous attemps on Monday as soon as I have access to my workstation.

---

EDIT:
It seems like my description of the desired result was a bit misleading. I edited the desired result table in my question (there was a typo).

I basically need to compare all data in `PTRANSACT` that correspond to a 'D' transaction in `TRANSACT` (for example `t_id=100001`)  with all rows in `PTRANSACT` that correspond to a 'C' transaction (always `t_id+1`, for example `100002`).

I know how to select my 'D' transactions and how to find the corresponding 'C' transaction. My main problem is to get all data for both out of `PTRANSACT` (one set of n rows for each) and compare both sets with each other as a whole (not row by row).

Comment: Your results are the same as the first table and the second table seems totally superfluous.  I follow the question but the data confuses me.  I would expect results to have only debit transactions, for instance, based on the problem description.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My result table was wrong. I accidently copied the first table without removing the undesired rows. The edited version should be right now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH TRANSACTIONS(T_ID,TYPE,PRICE,ADD_INFO)AS
 (
   SELECT 100001  ,   'D'    ,   2000  ,        'Y' UNION ALL
   SELECT 100002  ,   'C'    ,  -2000  ,        'Y'  UNION ALL
   SELECT 100003  ,   'D'    ,   1000  ,        'Y'  UNION ALL
   SELECT 100004  ,   'C'   ,  -1000  ,       'Y'   UNION ALL
   SELECT 100005  ,   'D'    ,   3000  ,        'N'  UNION ALL  
   SELECT 100006  ,   'D'    ,   2000  ,        'Y'  UNION ALL
   SELECT 100007  ,   'C'    ,   1000  ,        'Y'   
),
PTTRANSACT(T_ID,PARTNER,CHARGE) AS
(
  SELECT 100001  ,      'AAA'  ,     200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100001  ,      'BBB'  ,     400 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100002  ,      'AAA'  ,    -200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100002  ,      'BBB'  ,    -400 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100003  ,      'AAA'  ,     100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100003  ,      'BBB'  ,     200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100004  ,      'AAA'  ,    -100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100006  ,      'CCC'  ,     600 UNION ALL
  SELECT 100007  ,      'CCC'  ,    -300 
),
PTTRANSACT_ROW_NUMBER AS
(
   SELECT PT.T_ID,PT.PARTNER,PT.CHARGE,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PT.T_ID ORDER BY PT.PARTNER ASC)AS XCOL  
   FROM PTTRANSACT AS PT
)
SELECT T.T_ID,T.TYPE,T.PRICE,T.ADD_INFO,PT1.PARTNER AS PT1_PARTNER,PT1.CHARGE AS   CHARGE_1,
PT2.PARTNER AS PT2_PARTNER,PT2.CHARGE AS CHARGE_2
FROM TRANSACTIONS AS T
LEFT JOIN PTTRANSACT_ROW_NUMBER AS PT1 ON T.T_ID=PT1.T_ID AND PT1.XCOL=1 
LEFT JOIN PTTRANSACT_ROW_NUMBER AS PT2 ON T.T_ID=PT2.T_ID AND PT2.XCOL=2
```

I am not sure if I understand your requirements in the right way and if this code is supported by DB2 on mainframe,but could you check it

1. TRANSACTIONS and PTTRANSACT - only to represent your tables
2. PTTRANSACT_ROW_NUMBER is created to determine first and second record for corresponding transaction. Then these records are join to the TRANSACTIONS to show first and second partner etc..

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find a way to output only Debit transactions that are not (!) followed by a Credit transaction so that both transactions cancel each other out.

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(type) over (order by t_id) as next_type,
             lead(price) over (order by t_id) as next_price
      from t
     ) t
where type = 'D' and
      ( not (next_type = 'C' and price + next_price = 0) or
        next_type is null
      );
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the desired result table  in my question. The second table shouldn't be superfluous. I basically need to compare all rows in the second table that correspond to a 'D' transaction with all rows that correspond to the 'C' transaction. I know how to select my 'D' transactions and how to find the corresponding 'C' transaction. My main problem is to get all data for both transactions from the second table (two sets of n rows) and compare both sets with each other (as a whole, not row by row)